# Mysql regex for finding space separated number 0

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to find the space separated number '0'. Need to use in my sql query to search for some results. I used `[[:<:]]0[[:>:]]` but this is returning **0%, 0.5% ,0.00, 1.0** along with actual result like **Rs 0**

What should I use to only fetch valid results which doesn't include these results like 0% or 0.5 or 1.0

```
Edited: Solution given by Rahul was correct but I also found alternative solution->

 WHERE column_name REGEXP '([[:blank:]]|^)0([[:blank:]]|$)'
```

Comment: `[[:<:]]` means "start of word boundary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it without regex like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(' ', mycol, ' ') LIKE '% 0 %'
```

And if the 0 is at the beginning or end then you can use OR

```
WHERE CONCAT(' ', mycol, ' ') LIKE '% 0 %' OR
CONCAT('', mycol, ' ') LIKE '%0 %' OR
CONCAT(' ', mycol, '') LIKE '% 0%'
```

Comment: is there a method using the regex only as I have to match mutiple patterns like i am using WHERE column REGEXP '^no| [[:<:]]free[[:>:]]'

Comment: btw this above expression does work!!.....any method to find it using REGEXP only??